# How to use Sharepoint CSR to conditional hide row

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering, hide-elements, script-webpart, script-editor-webpart

Team,

I've got a list to record a shift roster. I have two Date/Time columns recording (1) Start of the shift and (2) End of the Shift.

I want a view that only shows who is rostered on right now!

I can use OOTB list filters to filter by [today] but not by time - which means it picks up all shifts that either start or end on the same date as "today".

The code below paints any row green if shift start date/time <= to "now" AND if shift end date/time => to "now" and anything that does not match that criteria is painted red (my workaround to the whole inability of filtering by time).

GREAT! - however, rather than paint green or red, I want to show TRUE rows and hide FALSE rows.

I just haven't found the code yet on the 'net that I can scavenge and rejig to do the job. Any help would be appreciated.

Don't care if its a pre or post render. Thought pre-render will probably by better?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    //OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
    OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
            // get today's date
            var today = new Date();

            // get the Start Date and Time          
            var startDateTime = rows[i]["StartDateTime"]; //static name "StartDateTime"  Format: 31/03/2018 7:00 AM
            var startDateTimeParts = startDateTime.split(" ");
            var startDate = (startDateTimeParts[0]); // date
            var startTime = (startDateTimeParts[1]); // time

            // Split startDate
            var startDateParts = startDate.split("/");
            var startDateYear = (startDateParts[2]); // Year
            var startDateMonth = (startDateParts[1]); // Month
            var startDateDay = (startDateParts[0]); // Day              

            // Split startTime
            var startTimeParts = startTime.split(":");
            var startTimeHour = (startTimeParts[0]); // Hour
            var startTimeMinutes = (startTimeParts[1]); // Minute
            var startTimeSeconds = (startTimeParts[2]); // Seconds

            var startDateTimeValue = new Date(startDateYear,startDateMonth-1,startDateDay,startTimeHour,startTimeMinutes,0,0);

            // get the End Date and Time            
            var endDateTime = rows[i]["EndDateTime"]; //static name "EndDateTime" Format: 31/03/2018 7:00 AM
            var endDateTimeParts = endDateTime.split(" ");
            var endDate = (endDateTimeParts[0]); // date
            var endTime = (endDateTimeParts[1]); // time

            // Split endDate
            var endDateParts = endDate.split("/");
            var endDateYear = (endDateParts[2]); // Year
            var endDateMonth = (endDateParts[1]); // Month
            var endDateDay = (endDateParts[0]); // Day              

            // Split endTime
            var endTimeParts = endTime.split(":");
            var endTimeHour = (endTimeParts[0]); // Hour
            var endTimeMinutes = (endTimeParts[1]); // Minute
            var endTimeSeconds = (endTimeParts[2]); // Seconds

            var endDateTimeValue = new Date(endDateYear,endDateMonth-1,endDateDay,endTimeHour,endTimeMinutes,0,0);



            var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 

//alert("new start d/t: " + startDateTimeValue);
//alert("new end d/t: " + endDateTimeValue);

            if (startDateTimeValue <= today && endDateTimeValue >= today) {
                row.style.backgroundColor = '#01DF3A';  //green
//alert("startDateTimeValue: " + startDateTimeValue + " <= today: " + today + " && endDateTimeValue: " + endDateTimeValue);
            } else {
                row.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4d4d';  //red
//alert("NOT = startDateTimeValue: " + startDateTimeValue + " <= today: " + today + " && endDateTimeValue: " + endDateTimeValue);                   
            }

        }
    }
}); 
});

</script>
```

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you definitely don't want pre-render because there are no DOM elements there to hide yet.

I believe you should be able to set the row's `display` style setting to "none" right in the code that you have.

Something like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {

            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

                var today = new Date();

                // can you not just create the DateTime objects directly from
                // the field values?  i am certain i have done this before,
                // i don't think you need to do all the string splitting

                var startDateTimeValue = new Date(rows[i]["StartDateTime"]);
                var endDateTimeValue = new Date(rows[i]["EndDateTime"]);

                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);

                if (startDateTimeValue <= today && endDateTimeValue >= today) {
                    row.style.backgroundColor = '#01DF3A';  //green
                } else {
                    row.style.display = 'none'; // hidden                   
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```